# How does the flight trajectory of a GEO vs LEO mission vary for a Falcon 9 first stage?

Tags: launch, spacex, rockets, falcon-9

How does the trajectory vary between the two types of missions? Specifically, how does the speed and velocity vary for the booster for a Falcon 9 mission?

Comment: Check https://flightclub.io/ which has profiles for previous SpaceX flights (iirc the author corrects them by matching the telemetry data from webcast) together with estimated profiles for some upcoming missions.

Answer (score -3):

$Q2E \cdot \frac{VqE2}{Mass} \cdot \frac{thrust ratio}{V_e}$ on slow line exit to HEO to exit Ve to Max thrust to shut down and IqU2EvVe Is Pion Start up Pq2ExW/Mass to LqM x Ve = Tqr Thrust mass QVe to transition.

Comment: The site supports Latex formatting. I made a partial conversion of your formulas into latex, but I was incapable to decode, what you wanted to write. So if you know latex, please do the rest. Your formulas are probably incomprehensible for the readers in their current form.

Comment: how to write LaTeX/Mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference